# How to filter multiple users accounts in Node.js Twitter RetweetBot

Tags: node.js, twitter

Learning from videos and tutorials, I've put a basic Twitter Retweet bot together and host it on Heroku. In the example below, it retweets up to 10 tweets with the hashtags #sunshine, #rainbow or #lollipops. The actual bot retweets hashtags within a certain interest area though.

It filters nativeretweets so it won't retweet retweets. It filters tweets with the words Youtube, Twitch or NSFW in. It filter tweets from the accounts @Account01 and @Account02.

The problem is that a lot of accounts jump on the back of hashtags and tweet things unrelated to them. @Account01 and @Account02 in this example are two of these accounts. Unfortunately there are for example 20 more accounts and growing every day. There are also a handful of accounts who tweet hateful stuff under the hashtag.

If I make this line too long by adding OR from:Account03 OR from:Account04 OR from:Account05, etc the bot stops working completely. Blocking/muting the accounts from the bot account also doesn't seem to affect this, so it still retweets them.

Does anyone know what I might be able to add to filter a higher number of accounts out and stop them being retweet? Please do note that I am very much a self-taught beginner learning informally, so apologies if this is a basic question.

When asking about this before, someone implied that the Twitter automation rules should be looked at but as far as I can tell, it's fully compliant with all rules. There may have been some misunderstanding as I've changed some details to obscure things or someone just misread thinking that it doesn't filter NSFW tags, but instead promotes it. Or there may be something I'm misunderstanding, but this is a spin-off of a basic Twitter bot tutorial and there are many similar accounts.

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var config = require('./config.js');
var Tweet = new Twitter(config);

var params = {
      q: '(#Rainbow OR #Sunshine OR #Lollipops) -(filter:nativeretweets OR Youtube OR Twitch OR NSFW OR from:Account01 OR from:Account02) since:2020-01-01',
      count: 10,
      result_type: 'recent',
      lang: 'en'    
    } 

Tweet.get('search/tweets', params, function(err, data, response) {
    if(!err){
        for(let i = 0; i < data.statuses.length; i++){
            let id = { id: data.statuses[i].id_str }
            Tweet.post('statuses/retweet', id, function(err, response){
              if(err){
                console.log(err[0].message);
              }
              else{
                let username = response.user.screen_name;
                let tweetId = response.id_str;
                console.log('Retweeted: ', `https://twitter.com/${username}/status/${tweetId}`)
              }
            });
          }
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
```

Comment: Does it make sense to do filtering in your code instead of sending a complex query to the Twitter API?

Comment: +1 for what @Peter suggested - this is a typical pattern for Twitter API development where you do whatever query you can and filter results locally. In particular, the search API has complexity limits (that they mention in the docs without a spec on what they are) on the query and will error out when you exceed them.

Comment: Thanks @Peter and Joe - I'm quite new, so I'm not too sure on how to filter results locally in the code. It gives me a hint on what to look into though.